# oracle 12c materialized view becomes invalid but no ddl happened to master

Tags: oracle, materialized-views, mv, recompile

I'm using 4 materialized views on my oracle 12c - all of them are updated manually by a stored procedure call.

All views include a lookup to context variable in where clause including a time span (from and to).

Context was created by

```
CREATE OR REPLACE CONTEXT myContext using prepare_export;
```

No view has any relation to other views except using the same user context but different variable names.

Execution Chain is (only one view should be refreshed):

```
execute prepare_export('MyViewName','20180131','20180231');
```

1. entry in data_export table is generated for data_export logging

   ```
   INSERT INTO DATA_EXPORT 
   (SOURCE_,EXPORT_TIME_,EXPORT_FROM_,EXPORT_TO_,user_name,user_ip) 
   VALUES (viewName,systimestamp,date_From,date_To,(select user from dual),(select sys_context('userenv','ip_address') from dual));`
   ```
2. context variables are set (from:20180131 and to:20180231)

   ```
   dbms_session.set_context('myContext',viewName || '_from',date_from);
   dbms_session.set_context('myContext',viewName || '_to',date_to);
   ```
3. view MyViewName gets refreshed (atomic refresh false)

   ```
   dbms_mview.refresh(viewName,'c',atomic_refresh=>FALSE);
   ```
4. data_export entry gets updated with count(*) of last refresh

   ```
   execute immediate 'UPDATE data_export set resultset_size_=' ||viewRowCount ||' where id_ = (select max(id_) from data_export where source_=''' || viewName || ''' group by source_)';
   ```

After the procedure has completed all views become invalid and need to be recompiled manually...

Any help out there?

Thx, Joe

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know. However:

> ... all of them are updated manually by a stored procedure call (...)
>   After the procedure has completed all views become invalid and need to
>   be recompiled manually

Why wouldn't you include your *manual recompilation* command into the above mentioned stored procedure?

Comment: sure this may work - but it fixes not the cause. By the way - I tried this already but sometimes it did not work - only if I call the recompile some seconds after completion of the stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

... I reduced the stored procedure contents to just update a very simple (select count(*)) and new materialized view - without any other insert, update, context...blabla

==> all views needs recompile afterwards...

Comment: ok - its reproducible with simple materialized views and simple master. Sometimes the views become invalid after master DML happens sometimes not - it depends on if a refresh of view was done before and no compile happened... But it's not 100 percent deterministic...